How to use JPA with LocalDateTime and where queries
I am in a spring boot application and I use JPA
I have an entity (I removed what is useless for this question) :
data class Subscriber(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    val id: String? = null,
    @Column(name = "subscribed_date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    val subscribedDate: LocalDateTime,
)

And the repository
interface SubscriberRepository : JpaRepository<Subscriber, String> {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(s) FROM Subscriber s WHERE s.campaign.account = :account AND s.subscribedDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
    fun countNewSubscribersByAccountBetweenDate(account: Account, startDate: LocalDateTime, endDate: LocalDateTime): Long
String): Long

I use Sqllite in dev and pgsql in production
The query do not return anything in dev env and it's because of the dates
Here is how I call this method
val endDate = LocalDateTime.now()
val startDate = endDate.minusDays(28)
println(subscriberRepository.countNewSubscribersByAccountBetweenDate(account, startDate, endDate))

The result is always 0. Even if I know that I have some records between those dates
In dev environment
I have the following configuration
spring.datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlite:data/db.db?date_class=TEXT
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa:
    properties:
        hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    database-platform: org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update

In production environment, with pgsql, the query works.
Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work locally with sqlite ?

String isn't a LocalDateTime, the types should match, JPA will then do the conversion. Or change it in the entity to String so that it matches.

yes sorry, the provided code is not the right one. I have indeed methods with LocalDateTime. I'll edit the sample

If you are using Postgres in production I suggest to use that for testing as well. Especially with testcontainers and the fast startup times of Postgres with that there is no reason not to use it. Using a substitute is always that a substitute. \

Ok, the problem was absolutely not my code...
I use intellij to connect to the database. But had not the same settings to connect
And I modified the date through intellij. So the date were stored as timestamp
To avoid that, I had to change the connection properties

This way, dates are correctly stored. And it works again...

You probably do not want to store this as a String.  For instance, it's grossly inefficient to do any kind of database operation on a Date that's stored as a String

SQlite don't have a specific datetime. It's either text, real or integer.
I know I had a problem with REAL and INTEGER storage and that's why I've decided to use text but I don't remember my problem back then ^^
Anyway, I only use SQlite in my dev environment. Performance are not important for this env.
